# Grey border line on textarea when i use firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, line

i have a problem with my webpage: When i use firefox and a text area in my html, i can see in this textarea a border line of 2-3px grey, how you can see in my page: http://rossimelthomas.com/contact.html.
In your opinion how can i fix this problem?

if you don't understand what is the problem, i can send a screenshot to you, anyway thanks for all your future helps (maybe) and sorry for my english.
i post here my html:

```html
<form action="php/mail_send.php" method="POST">
        <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='Name') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Name'" style="border: solid 1px; border-radius: 5px; height:25px; border-color: white; width: 65%; "  value="Name" type="text" name="name">
        <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='E-Mail') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'E-Mail'" style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px;  height:25px; border-color: white; width: 65%" value="E-Mail" type="email" name="email">
        <input autocomplete="off" onfocus="if (this.value=='Subject') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'Subject'" style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px; height:25px;  border-color: white; width: 65%" value="Subject" type="text" name="subject">
        <textarea class="txt_field" style="    color: #99a0aa;margin-top: 20px;  font: normal normal 16px/20px pnova-regular, helvetica, sans-serif; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 5px; border-color: white; width: 65%; height: 300px;" type="text" name="message">Message</textarea>
        <input style="margin-top: 20px; border: thin 1px; border-radius: 10px; border-color: white; cursor:pointer; margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: #4db849; width:65%; height: 45px; color: white; font-weight: 700;" type="submit" value="Send Message">
        </form>
```

Comment: You're using border on textarea so you're seeing border, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your input says it has a border

```
<textarea class="txt_field" style="    color: #99a0aa;margin-top: 20px;  font: normal normal 16px/20px pnova-regular, helvetica, sans-serif; border: thin 1px;
```

note the last few words on that line:
"border: thin 1px;"

change it to "border: 0px" to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the textarea completely? Every browser has default settings for inputs, textarea and that kind of stuff.

```
textarea {
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your input fields:

```
border: none;
outline: none;
```

It will remove border and blue lines around fields on focus.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out within textarea css

`-webkit-appearance: none;`